# Make directory and copy some file on a path which is parent of home directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, permissions

OK I don't know terms in server, ubuntu and everything related them;
So I try to explain my problem in detail.

**The version of Ubuntu on my server is 14.04.5**

I have an account on my VPS server which name is ati, when I log in by ati, I use below command:

```
ssh ati@167.xxx.xxx.xxx
ati@167.xxx.xxx.xxx's password: 
ati@usa239:~$ cd ..
ati@usa239:/home$ ls
ati  xv
ati@usa239:/home$ cd ..
ati@usa239:/$ ls
aquota.group  boot  home        lib     media  proc  sbin  tmp            var      webmin-setup.out
aquota.user   dev   initrd.img      lib64   mnt    root  srv   usermin-setup.out  vmlinuz
bin       etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt    run   sys   usr            vmlinuz.old
```

For some reason I need to create a directory and copy some files at it but when I try to make directory I got below error:

```
ati@usa239:/$ ssh mkdir Tracker
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mkdir: Name or service not known
```

I have tried to add permission by below command:

```
ati@usa239:/$ sudo chmod -R 777 .
[sudo] password for ati: 
chmod: changing permissions of './aquota.group': Operation not permitted
...
```

Now I have question, Is It possible to add a directory at this path?
How can I do something which helps me?

Many thanks

Comment: Please 1) don't `sudo chmod -R 777 .` you will must likely regret it. And don't `ssh mkdir Tracker` once in it should be `mkdir tracker`. 2) Now please talk to your VPS admin, `quota` is set and can't be overwritten by you.

Comment: I say this with the kindest possible intent. It looks like you're a beginning Linux user, and I'd strongly encourage that you learn more about the basic Linux command line verbs before trying to do what you're doing. Either take a Linux class, or purchase a "Introduction to Linux" book, and study a bit first. You'll save your admin a whole lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Once logged in, make sure you are in your home folder by typing the following command:

```
cd ~
```

The "**~**" is a representation for your home folder.

From here, just type the following command to create a directory.

```
mkdir tracker
```

To check if this has been successful, you can type the following command:

```
ls
```

This will give you an output of all the folders in your current folder. If you need to check the permissions on them, you can type the following command:

```
ls -l
```

which will give you a list of all the folders along with their permissions.